# Is every connected solvable group Borel?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, solvable-groups

Is every connected solvable algebraic group a Borel subgroup of a reductive group? If a counterexample exists, I would ideally like it to be over $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Yes, every unimodular solvable algebraic that is not a torus is not a Borel subgroup of any reductive group (a torus being Borel of itself). Also most non-unimodular solvable 3-dimensional algebraic groups are not Borel either.

Comment: What’s a unimodular solvable group? Also, would you be able to explain why these are counterexamples?

Comment: For an algebraic group, the modular character is given by $g\mapsto\det(\mathrm{Ad}(g))$. Unimodular means that this character has finite image (for connected, it means it is trivial).

Comment: (And why that lets us recognise counterexamples is that the modular character of the Borel subgroup of a reductive group is $2\rho$ on a maximal torus, where $\rho$ is the half-sum of positive roots; and this is non-$0$ unless the group equals its torus.)  But note that @YCor's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/375981/is-every-connected-solvable-group-borel#comment953262_375981) means "No, not every connected soluble algebraic group is a Borel subgroup of a reductive group".

Comment: @YCor Is there a characterization of which connected solvable groups are a Borel of a reductive group?

Comment: Yes, but I'd say: you have a classification of simple complex groups (and the 1-dimensional torus), and the classification follows (taking direct products of such things), maybe modulo finite central subgroups. I don't really see what an intrinsic condition would be, except that being Borel is very rare, and there are many obvious necessary conditions in terms of geometry of weights).